# Submitting forms to different server in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am following the [HtmlService documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service) in creating a form and automatically submitting it to make post request to another server.

I created something like:

```
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    "Loading.. <form action='http://xyz.com/abc' method='post' id='foo' />
    <input type='hidden' name='data' value='xyz' />  
    <script>document.getElementById('foo').submit(); </script>" )
```

It was working fine initially, but now the form is not submitted automatically as soon as this code runs. A blank page (with word loading) is displayed instead and no redirects. Can I know how can I automatically submit the forms on page load so that the post request is made to another server with required data.

Answer (score 0):

This is now tracked in the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1995) as #1995. I tried a few workarounds like using the jQuery ready function, auto clicking the submit button or setTimeouts but doesn't work. Please star the issue so you can track this.